# sql: prepend/append something to email field

Tags: sql, postgresql, obfuscation, email-address

I routinely import a copy of the production database, replacing my development database.

However, during development, I don't want t accidently email any production users. (their emails are stored in the `email` column of the `users` table)

How can I update all the email addresses so that if I accidentally email them, it goes to `nowhere`

if would also be nice if the original email is somehow embedded in the faked email.

Comment: You should have Test Mailserver wich accept mails and do. not Sent it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given: the email column holds one email (no commas, no monkey hacks, hidden commands - just an email). Then:

```
update users set email=email||'.fail';
```

Will update all email, adding `.fail` to the end where email is not null, if it is null, it will remain such. To revert back, run:

```
update users set email=substring(email,1,length(email)-5) 
  where substring(email from '.....$') = '.fail';
```

example of dataset:

```
t=# with users(email) as (values('pop@pop.pop'||'.fail'),(null))
select substring(email,1,length(email)-5) from users where substring(email from '.....$') = '.fail';
  substring
-------------
 pop@pop.pop
(1 row)
```